# Plotly legend entry to show/hide all plotting characters

Tags: r, plotly

Suppose I am building a plotly scatterplot that displays three different groups (here specified by colour). I can show/hide each group individually by clicking at the groups in the legend.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
d <- data.frame("a" = sample(1:50, 20, T), "b" = sample(1:50, 20, T), 
                        "col" = factor(sample(1:3, 20, T)))
        gg <- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = a, y = b, color = col), data = d)
        gg

plotly_build(gg)
```

Is there a way to add a button to the legend to show/hide all points ?

Comment: You mean an additional button to hide all? Or do you want to get rid of the individual functionality?

Comment: Can you expand on the use case, as I can't quite understand why you'd want to do this.  Understanding the purpose might help with thinking of the answer.

Comment: @MartinDabbelJuSmelter  I would like to add a button to show/hide all while still keeping the individual functionality. I have a very large scatterplot with 50 groups. When comparing only two or three groups of the 50 it is quite tedious to hide all others manually.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Would it help you to start with all the traces hidden by default and show them one at a time by clicking.  This will be a lot easer.

Comment: Yes, this would also work for me. Could you show me how to hide the traces by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to toggle all points simultaneously, but (as indicated in the comments that this would be a suitable alternative) it is possible to start with them all hidden and make points visible one at a time

```
plot_ly(data=d, x=a, y=b, type='scatter', mode='markers', color=col, visible='legendonly')
```

Answer (score 4):

This may be closer to what was originally asked for, but it is just a "button" not a legend entry, so placement is difficult.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
d <- data.frame("a" = sample(1:50, 20, T), "b" = sample(1:50, 20, T), 
                "col" = factor(sample(1:3, 20, T)))
gg <- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = a, y = b, color = col), data = d)
gg

plotly_build(gg) %>%
layout(updatemenus = list(
    list(
        type = "buttons",
        direction = "right",
        xanchor = "center",
        yanchor = "top",
        showactive = FALSE,
        x = 1.05,
        y = 0.2,
        buttons = list(
            list(method = "restyle",
                 args = list("visible", "all"),
                 label = "show all"),
            list(method = "restyle",
                 args = list("visible", "legendonly"),
                 label = "hide all")
        )
    )
))
```

This produces (depending on the version of plotly) the following drop-down "buttons":

[image: plotly output showing expanded buttons]

I don't know how to dynamically update the buttons based on the current visibility or how to make both buttons permanently visible instead of only available through the drop-down menu.